# How to use union to join multiple tables with different column name

Tags: laravel

My query below is using union to select from both tables, but the 'archive_pickup.pickup_id_' and 'pickup_request.id' are not same column name and i want to output 'archive_pickup.pickup_id_' ]or 'pickup_request.id' in my view based on what table the record is gotten from since they are not the same column. So i get an error showing Undefined property: stdClass::$pickup_id_ (View:

My Controller

```
$archive_pickup = DB::table("archive_pickup")
    ->select("archive_pickup.pickup_id_","archive_pickup.sendername","archive_pickup.recipientname",
    "archive_pickup.pickupdate","archive_pickup.pickuptime","archive_pickup.deliverytime",
    "archive_pickup.status");
  
$all_pickups = DB::table("pickup_request")
    ->select("pickup_request.id","pickup_request.sendername","pickup_request.recipientname",
    "pickup_request.pickupdate","pickup_request.pickuptime","pickup_request.deliverytime",
    "pickup_request.status")
    ->union($archive_pickup)
    ->get();
  
 return view('all_pickups',['all_pickups' => $all_pickups]);
```

My View

In my view, how can i output pickup_id_ column gotten from archive_pickup table or id column gotten from the pickup_request table based on the record retrived since the column name are not the same.

```
 @foreach($all_pickups as $all_pickup)
   <tr> 
       <td>{{ $all_pickup->pickup_id_ || $all_pickup->id}}</td>
   </tr> 
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try do it using [property_exists](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/property-exists-function-in-php)

```
  @foreach($all_pickups as $all_pickup)
       <tr> 
           <td>
 @if(property_exists($all_pickup,'pickup_id_'))
{{-- there is pickup_id_ --}}
@else
{{-- there is no pickup_id_ so it must be id --}}
@endif
          </td>
       </tr> 
     @endforeach
```